# pass data between to angular 2 tags

Tags: angular

I new in Angular 2 and I want to pass data one component tag to another component tag.

**component tag1**

```
<div class="row">

    <pie-chart></pie-chart>

</div>
```

**component tag 2**

```
<div class="row">
       <basic-table></basic-table>
</div>
```

these both component is placed in another component html file.

Comment: How are these components related (parent-child, siblings, unrelated, added by the router, ...) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

just use a global service to store the data and then using the same service extract the data in the other component

Answer (score 0):

Create a service..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {

  private _data: any;

  public store (data: any) {
    this._data = data;
  }

  public restore (): any {
    return this._data;
  }
}
```

Inject it to your components with DI (dependency injection):

`constructor (private _myService: YourService) { }`

and you can use this service inside of your components:

```
this._myService.store({..});
let data = this._myService.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a event emitter where you emit an event when something happens in one of the directive. 
The other one should subscribe to that event.

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
```

It has the following definition type

```
class EventEmitter {
    constructor(isAsync?: boolean)
    emit(value?: T)
    subscribe(generatorOrNext?: any, error?: any, complete?: any) : any
}
```

For more details refer to the documentation https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html